# How Weka draw ROC curve from KNN (IBk)?

Tags: weka, knn, roc

I have read a lot about ROC curve before posting.

So, I didn't understand how Weka draw the ROC curves. I can't find the thereshold to variate to generate the points in the curve.  Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226043/does-anyone-know-how-to-generate-auc-roc-area-based-on-the-predition
Please use the search function, there is lot of stuff here about ROC curves and Weka

Comment: I didn't ask how Weka calculates the AUC. I asked how Weka draw the ROC Curves, because Weka use a Thereshold Instances to get all the points in ROC Curve.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know it uses thresholds? Can you point us to the specific class? Because in general, you don't need a threshold.

Comment: Yeah, I need a thereshold. Each point (FPRxTPR) is get using something. This rates is getting using a thereshold, i.e, a specific value. For example, a instance is true if his value is upper than X, false otherwise.

Comment: For nominal attribute, is used a probability thereshold. [See](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ROC+curves) and [Eibe's book](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html).

Answer (score 0):

Weka uses a class called `TheresholdCurve` from a method in the `Evaluation` class.
In this class there are all the points of the ROC Curve.

The threshold will variate depending on the classification used. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226043/does-anyone-know-how-to-generate-auc-roc-area-based-on-the-predition) for more details.